# Do all transient allocations have unique address?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

While reading comments of a C++ Weekly [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRTmkDiW5MM) about the constexpr new support in C++20 I found the comment that alleges that C++20 allows UB in constexpr context.

At first I was convinced that comment is right, but more I thought about it more and more I began to suspect that C++20 wording contains some clever language that makes this defined behavior.

Either that all transient allocations return unique addresses or maybe some more general notion in C++ that makes 2 distinct allocation pointers always(even in nonconstexpr context) compare false even if at runtime in reality it is possible that allocator would give you back same address(since you deleted the first allocation).

As a bonus weirdness: you can only use `==` for comparison, `<`, `>` fail...

Here is the program with alleged UB in constexpr:

```
#include <iostream>
static constexpr bool f()
{
    auto p = new int(1);
    delete p;    
    auto q = new int(2);
    
    delete q;
            
    return p == q;
}
int main()
{
    constexpr bool res1 = f();
    
    std::cout << res1 << std::endl; // May output 0 or 1
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4bjTha7xo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result here is implementation-defined. `res1` could be false, true, or ill-formed, based on how the implementation wants to define it. And this is just as true for equality comparison as it is for relational comparison.

Both [[expr.eq]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#1.sentence-2) (for equality) and [[expr.rel]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel#1.sentence-3) (for relational) start by doing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on the pointers (because we have to actually read what the value is to do a comparison). [[conv.lval]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#3) says that the result of that conversion is:

> Otherwise, if the object to which the glvalue refers contains an invalid pointer value ([basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation], [basic.stc.dynamic.safety]), the behavior is implementation-defined.

That is the case here: both pointers contain an invalid pointer value, as per [[basic.stc.general]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#general-4):

> When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values. Indirection through an invalid pointer value and passing an invalid pointer value to a deallocation function have undefined behavior. Any other use of an invalid pointer value has implementation-defined behavior.

with a footnote reading:

> Some implementations might define that copying an invalid pointer value causes a system-generated runtime fault.

So the value we get out of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is... implementation-defined. It could be implementation-defined in a way that causes those two pointers to compare equal. It could be implementation-defined in a way that causes those two pointers to compare *not* equal (as apparently all implementations do). Or it could even be implementation-defined in a way that causes the comparison between those two pointers to be unspecified or undefined behavior.

Notably, [[expr.const]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5) (the main rule governing constant expressions), despite rejecting undefined behavior and explicitly rejecting any comparison whose result is *unspecified* ([[expr.const]/5.23](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.23)), says nothing about a comparison whose result is implementation-defined.

There's no undefined behavior here. Anything goes. Which is admittedly very weird during constant evaluation, where we'd expect to see a stricter set of rules.

Notably, with `p < q`, it appears that gcc and clang reject the comparison as being not a constant expression (which is... an allowed result) while msvc considers both `p < q` and `p > q` to be constant expressions whose value is `false` (which is... also an allowed result).

Comment: yikes! 
At least on the bright side of things the YT comment was correct(not about UB, about 0,1).
And I wish C++23 would fix this, but I will not be too sad if experts focus on other stuff, this should probably be very low priority since this is not a real code issue, more like ugly corner case, and properly specifying it is probably a huge amount of work. :)